# MySQL - How to remove subquery and simplify - calculate increase rate of sales by year

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I'm newbie to MySQL and trying to figure out if there's a way to simplify my query to get "how much percentage the sales increased from 2014 to 2015". Please see the

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a41a55/8).

Though the result is right, I used a lot of subqueries.

Here's my idea:

```
SELECT s15.store_id, SUM(s15.sales)/SUM(s14.sales) - 1
FROM STORE S15 INNER JOIN STORE S14
    ON S15.store_id = S14.store_id
WHERE S15.year = 2015 and s14.year = 2014
GROUP BY S15.year, S14.year
```

For tips to optimize, pls feel free to let me know. Tnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation and one `group by`:

```
SELECT store_id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(order_date) = 2014 THEN order_amount END) AS sell_2014,
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(order_date) = 2015 THEN order_amount END) AS sell_2015
FROM Orders
WHERE YEAR(order_date) IN ( 2014, 2015 )
GROUP BY store_id
```

I'll leave the arithmetic for the rate of increase up to you.